# How do I make specific cell groups in table scrollable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have [image: this bulky table] in excel.

How do I make the cell groups containing over 5 words scrollable? E.g. if I want the **expressing an opinion** for **A2** to only contain five visible cells and a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the Text Box (ActiveX Control).

1. Go to Developer > Controls group > Insert > Text Box, then insert a text box with right size, wide enough and high enough to contain words that you need.

[image]

2. Right click the text box > Properties.

   - Change MultiLine to be **True**, it means Word Wrap.
   - Change Scrollbars to be **2-fmScrollBarsVertical**, it means vertical
     scroll bar.

[image]

3. Click Design Mode to close design mode.
4. Copy the words into text box, or enter words and press Ctrl + Enter to wrap.

[image]

You may go into Design Mode, click text box and adjust size.